# Hung up on For In Loop and variable for external table loader

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to load a number of files every day into our database system.  My solution was to use a java procedure to generate a table of all the files in the directory folder and loop through each of them through the external table loader.  I'm running into two hangups with this

```
Declare
what_to_load     VARCHAR2(255);

CURSOR folder_contents 
IS 
   select filename
   from database.DIR_LIST
   where filename like 'DCOpenOrders_%'
   and filename like '%.csv';

BEGIN
  DELETE FROM database.DIR_LIST;
  database.GET_DIR_LIST( 'directory_path_files_are_in' );
FOR each_record IN folder_contents
  LOOP

what_to_load := each_record.filename;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP table database.my_table';

execute immediate 'CREATE table database.my_table
        (Region                 VARCHAR2(10),
         District               VARCHAR2(10),
         Originating_Store      VARCHAR2(80),
         Order_Date             VARCHAR2(30),
         Ship_Location          VARCHAR2(10),
         Orig_Ord_No            VARCHAR2(30),
         Field_G                VARCHAR2(30),
         Line_No                VARCHAR2(10),
         POS_UPC                VARCHAR2(30),
         Item_Descr             VARCHAR2(80),
         Ord_Qty                VARCHAR2(10),
         Line_Status            VARCHAR2(30),
         Report_Date            VARCHAR2(30),
         Ship_Type              VARCHAR2(30),
         ERR_FLAG               VARCHAR2(10),
         ERR_LOG                VARCHAR2(800)
        )
         ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
          ( type oracle_loader
            default directory WORK_DIR
            access parameters
            ( records delimited by NEWLINE
              skip 1
              fields terminated by '',''
              optionally enclosed by ''"''
              missing FIELD VALUES are NULL)
              location ('''||each_record.filename||''')
             )
              reject limit unlimited';

Execute Immediate 'Grant All on database.my_table to USER';
* merge statement goes here*
End Loop;
commit;
end;
```

Again, the idea is that every time this runs it will get the new list of csv files in the dir_list table with the java procedure get_dir_list, then for every file name I set as equal to the variable and use the variable in the external table loader to load up the file.

I'm running into [s]two[/s] problems

EDIT:  Ok, making the corrections below to cursor row identification, now I hit the point where when I go to the second pass through my cursor appears to be wrong or missing - it will go through a loop just fine if the only action is to do a put_line.  But with an execute immediate statement in there such as the "Grant All" then as soon as it completes one pass it throws ORA-08103 at the top of the loop and refuses to go on

3) I'm aware of an ask tom on this (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:37593123416931) that says to use the alter table command.  However when I try that it doesn't accept my attempt at that

```
execute immediate 'alter table database.my_table location('''||filename||''')';
```

throws out an error (plus I'd still need to get it to do another loop there to put the name of the current file into the external loader)

Any suggestions or help?  I should note that we are on windows, not unix (since most solutions people offer on these places assume the latter) and I can't grab another program or module to do the job due to approval restrictions (since that seems to be another common solution)

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what's the error???

Comment: For point one the error is PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type.  For point 2 there is no error message, it just gets hung up executing until you kill the process

Comment: And for point 3, the alter that "throws out an error"? I'd guess that is also getting PLS-00382 for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, your cursor loop variable is confusingly called `filename`. Your are referring to that *record* directly, instead of the column from the cursor. Changing the name slightly to make it a little clearer:

```
FOR filenames IN folder_contents
  LOOP

what_to_load := filesnames.filename;
```

The rest is less obvious, but it isn't going to be happy that you're dropping and recreating the table in the middle of a block that refers to it statically. You need to make all references dynamic:

```
execute immediate 'Grant All on database.my_table ...';
-- grant to who/what? and why?
```

And your merge will have to be dynamic too. At least unless you can get the alter table to work, but you haven't said what the problem is with that. Actually, from what you posted, that's the same cursor variable reference problem:

```
execute immediate 'alter table database.my_table location('''||filenames.filename||''')';
```

If you aren't dropping/creating the table in the block, and create it once statically and just alter it, then you can use a static merge - just the alter needs to be dynamic.

---

A simpler approach might be to create the external table once, with a specific fixed name; loop through the list of real files; and for each of those in turn, rename or copy that to the fixed file name and perform the merge. Each time you query the external table it rereads the file anyway, so changing its contents in the background is OK. Dropping/recreating or even altering the table then wouldn't be necessary.

You could also, as that Ask Tom pst mentions, supply all the file names to the external table at once, as they have the same structure, either with the drop/create or with the alter approach.

Comment: This (the being more specific on the record in the cursor) helped with the variable linking, but it still gets hung up as soon as it completes the first pass through the loop and goes back to the start.

The grant is because of the merge and some other operations I need to do later in this procedure, I grant it to a  specific profile but didn't want to post that online due to company privacy concerns.

Comment: I guess the grant must be dynamic in your real code anyway. Is the merge? How are you checking it does the first merge and goes back to the start of the loop?

Comment: No, I had the grant as a general to the profile, no variables in it, it just refers to the table I just created.

The merge is from the temp table to a staging table, nothing dynamic there.  Right now I am not testing that part; I have it commented out.  Presently I'm just seeing if I can loop through the list to load everything.

Comment: But grant is DDL, so it has to be executed dynamically, PL/SQL doesn't recognise it. Anyway... I can't duplicate it hanging. Maybe there's some other factor you've left out. Aside from commenting bits out until it works to narrow it down, or looking for blocking/blocked statements, not sure what to suggest. Sorry.

Comment: I tried running it so that the cursor would have only one record in it; after the first pass rather than exiting it threw ORA-08103: object no longer exists.  Which is new and maybe related to it getting hung up on the loop

Comment: and now when I do it again it just hangs up after doing the first pass rather than recognizing it is at the end of the loop and should move on

Comment: I still can't reproduce, and can't see what in the code you posted could cause either of those issues. Maybe it's something to do with the version and patch level you're using, or you're doing something that you haven't shown. Do you have the same problem with the `alter` approach?

Comment: Right now I have the alter statement commented out; I haven't tried that.